# C# Multiple Tasks Blocked On Invoke Line

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a scenario where I create 3 Tasks:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething("fu"));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething("man"));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething("chu"));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Each task simply passes its value to another method called Report() that tries to append text to a single textbox. Given the asynchronous scenario here, I check the InvokeRequired and also make use of a syncroot object.

```
private object syncRoot = new object();

public void DoSomething (string x)
{
    Report(x);
}

public void Report(string Message)
{
    if (txtLog != null)
    {
        if (txtLog.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txtLog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Report(Message)));
        }
        else
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                txtLog.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("o") + " :: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " :: " + Message.TrimEnd() + "\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this Report() code seems to work fine in other scenarios (where there's 1 async task), but in this scenario, each of the 3 tasks gets to the txtLog.Invoke(...) line and then hangs. If I pause execution via the debugger, I can see all 3 are just sitting at that line and are flagged as Blocked.

However, I'm not sure WHY that particular line would be blocked. Any ideas?

Comment: Where's the code for `DoSomething`? You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: DoSomething is currently nothing but a simple call to Report(). public void DoSomething(string x) { Report(x); }

Comment: You really should have stated that in the question.

Comment: I already had but I just updated the code part to say it more explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the combination of `Invoke` and `WaitAll`.
`Waitall` blocks the UI-thread until all tasks have finished.
But your tasks can only finish when the `Invoke` (also a blocking operation) has finished executing the delegate on the UI thread. This will never happen because the UI thread is already blocked waiting for the tasks to finish. Hence the deadlock.

**Solution 1:**

Use `BeginInvoke` instead. This runs the delegates asynchrounously, so exits the task immediately after scheduling the delegate, thus freeing the UI thread to execute those delegates:

```
public void Report(string Message)
{
    if (txtLog != null)
    {
        if (txtLog.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txtLog.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Report(Message)));
        }
        else
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                txtLog.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("o") + " :: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " :: " + Message.TrimEnd() + "\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Another solution (based on Fabio's suggestion) would be to make the eventhandler asynchronous and using `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. This solves the problem by not blocking the UI thread while waiting for the tasks to finish. In that case you can use `Invoke` without a problem:

```
  private async void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething("fu")));
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething("man")));
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething("chu")));
      await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
  }
```

Note: normally using `void` as a return type for a asynchrounous method is bad practice. Asynchronous handlers for UI events in Winforms require a `void` returntype, so there is no choice here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not actually related to concreate problem, but instead of creating workarounds for accessing UI controls from another thread, you can return required result from another thread and update textbox correctly on UI thread.

```
public string Report(string message)
{
    // some long calculation which should be executed on other thread
    return $"{DateTime.Now:o} :: {CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} :: {message.TrimEnd()};
}

private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tasks = new[]
    {
        Task.Run(() => Report("fu")),
        Task.Run(() => Report("man")),
        Task.Run(() => Report("chu")),
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    textLog.Text = tasks.Select(task => task.Result)
                        .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
                                   (builder, result) => builder.AppendLine(result), 
                                   builder => builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the idea but I'm trying to learn the reason behind the blocked threads so I can grow in my understanding of async C#

Comment: You should call `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` so you will get possible exception with more detailed information (without `await` any exception will be swallowed). Symptoms refer more to possible deadlock.

Comment: @Fabio; Task.WaitAll(...) really does propagate exceptions from the tasks (via an AggregateException). There is however another reason why await Task.WhenAll(tasks) is a could suggestion: it solves the problem :) (see my answer, 2nd solution ).